# complex number root

Tags: complex-numbers

I've tried to find all the 4 roots of the equation:
z^4 = (-2-i)^4.
I started by simplifying the right side(called it w) and the results was 
w=-7+24i
(I checked both in trigo and in polar ways)
But after that the calculations does not fit.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: You can use $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ a few times \begin{align}z^4-(-2-i)^4&=(z^4+(-2-i)^2)(z^2-(-2-i)^2)\\&=(z+i(-2-i))(z-i(-2-i))(z+(-2-i))(z-(-2-i))\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The roots of $z^4=(-2-i)^4$ are, setting $w=-2-i$

$z^4=w^4$

$z$ is all the four fourth roots of unity by $w$

$z_1=w;\;z_2=-w;\;z_3=iw;\;z_4=-iw$

hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

The roots of $z^n=w$ are $$z=\sqrt[n]{|w|}\exp\left(\frac{\arg(w)+2k\pi}{n}i\right)\qquad k\in\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$$
So for this case, $w=(-2-i)^4$ and $n=4$. Notice, $|w|=|-2-i|^4$ and $\arg(w)=4\arg(-2-i)$.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is clearly $z_0 = -2-i$. Next, note that since $z_0^4 = (-2-i)^4$, then we also have $(iz_0)^4 = i^4z_0^4 = z_0^4 = (-2-i)^4$. Similarily we also get $(-z_0)^4 = (-iz_0)^4 = (-2-i)^4$.

Thus we have found four solutions $z_0, iz_0, -z_0, -iz_0$. Since it's a degree four polynomial equation, there cannot be more than four solutions, so we are done.